# Error spawning multiple threads to delete multiple same elements

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-8

I want to delete same elements replicated 2353218 times keeping only one, in the xml. Tried to spawn the process but getting following error. without spawn it is taking too much time. Please help.

```
 xquery version "1.0-ml";
    let $input := doc("http://www.somedomain.com/name/12345.xml")/xpath/toMultipleElement[2 to last()]

    let $batch-size := 50000

    let $input-size := fn:count($input)

    let $num-batches :=  xs:int(math:ceil($input-size div $batch-size ))

    let $result :=
    <root>{

    for $batch-start in (1 to $num-batches)
      let $processing-seq := $input[($batch-size * ($batch-start - 1) + 1)  to ($batch-size * ($batch-start ))]
      return

        xdmp:spawn-function(function() {
        xdmp:node-delete($processing-seq),

        <success batch-start='{$batch-start}'> processing sequence deleted</success>
        }, 
        <options xmlns="xdmp:eval">
          <result>true</result>
          <transaction-mode>update-auto-commit</transaction-mode>
        </options>)
    }</root>

    return 
    xdmp:save("D:/batch-wise-delete.xml", $result)
```

Error: [1.0-ml] XDMP-DELEXTNODES: let $processing-seq := $input[$batch-size * ($batch-start - 1) + 1 to $batch-size * $batch-start] -- Cannot delete external nodes

Comment: I have the impression you are trying to omit elements from a long list, and save the filtered list to disk. You wouldn't use node-delete for that, but rather reconstruct the doc while omitting what you don't need. Can you confirm?

Comment: @grtjn, Actually one of the element in xml file got duplicated millions of time so I want to keep only first and delete rest all, hence I can restore original doc as it is. the operation report  I m storing to disk, i.e how many time delete got called.

Comment: The message 'cannot delete external nodes' is related to the spawning. You can pass nodes through, but you'll get a copy, which you can no longer node-update. You'd have to pass through doc-uri, and position info to retrieve a fresh copy of the node for deleting. But this is not an efficient way to get rid of so many elements in one doc..

Comment: so is there any efficient work around for this

Comment: Yes, see the answer by @DALDEI..

Answer (score 4):

Instead of deleting all the children, just write a new parent having one child.

```
let $parent := doc("http://www.somedomain.com/name/12345.xml")/xpath/parent
let $chosen-child := $parent/toMultipleElement[1]
return xdmp:node-replace($parent, <parent>{ $chosen-child }</parent>
```

Answer (score 3):

I recommend that instead of attempting to delete all the unwanted nodes that instead you reconstruct the document by inclusion in one pass.

The basic strategy is documented here `https://developer.marklogic.com/blog/xquery-recursive-descent`

essentially -- create a new document by recursing over all the nodes in the existing document and returning them unchanged *except* exlucde the unwanted nodes.
then save the new document over the old. 
This can be done in one transaction very efficiently.